# Accidentally emptied a Note, which was then automatically deleted

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app

I accidentally emptied the content of one of my Notes by selecting all and then pressing on the "return" key - removing everything.

I then quickly exited from my, now empty, Note, which my iPhone 8 *automatically* deleted.

And since this was an iCloud synced note it promptly synced it over to my Mac and deleted it from there.

So since technically I didn't delete it I can't find it in my "Recently Deleted Files". And checking my backup data on my iPhone there doesn't seem to be an option for Notes.

Comment: If you have iCloud backup on the phone a restore should bring it back to 'last night' if you left your phone on charge, in reach of wifi. For next time… shake the phone to undo.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to say this but I think your note is permanently deleted.

Here's why: 
Deleting text in a note is like deleting text in a Word-document. When you delete all text in a Word-document, you can still undo (using CMD+Z) while the document is open. If you closed the document, the undo history gets deleted. And I thinks iOS Notes works this way. Try to create a new Note, add some text, go back, exit the app (by swiping up) and open it again. Can you undo(shake the device) to remove text? No. Undo history is gone.

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution because if I manually delete a note it will appear in my "Recently Deleted" folder. But if the note is automatically deleted then it doesn't.

Comment: @user1021726 I tried to recreate you accident by selecting all notes and deleting them. They did appear in the recently deleted folder on iCloud.com. Either we have a bug here, or my recreation failed. Did I do any wrong in the recreation of the accident?

Comment: Hmm maybe. So I didn't select and delete all notes, I opened up a note and selected all text and deleted the text, then backed out of the note. And then iphone automatically deletes an all-empty note. Sorry if it wasn't clear before.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. No problem, we're here to help. I've successfully recreated your accident. I'm sorry to say this but I think your note is permanently deleted. Here's why: Deleting text in a note is like deleting text in a word document. When you delete all text in word, you can still undo (CMD+Z) while the document is open. If you closed the document, the undo history gets deleted. And I thinks iOS Notes works this way. Try to open a new Note, add some text, go back, exit the app(swipe up) and open it. Can you undo(shake) added text? No. Undo history is gone.

Comment: It's an important distinction to make that deleting the text in the note is not the same as deleting the note - the note was *modified*.  This is why you can't recover it from trash - the note was never trashed/deleted to begin with.

Comment: Yes that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to recover the Notes on your Mac using the [Local Snapshots](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015). Your Mac makes a backup of your changed files every hour, even when no external drive is connected.

1. In the Finder click on "Go to Folder ..." and go to ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/
2. Select all items in that folder
3. Enter the TimeMachine
4. Navigate to a recent backup before you have lost your Notes by clicking on the layers behind the top Finder window
5. Click on Resotre

Answer (score 0):

This is not on iPhone but on MacBook, but I've also lost several important notes just because I accidentally pressed Cmd + A, then Backspace key, and closed the app.

My solution was to **change the shortcut of 'Select All' from Cmd + A to Ctrl + A only for the notes app**, and it has been satisfying so far.

Howto:
System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts (left pane) > Click + button and add 'notes' > Register new shortcut for 'Select All' as Ctrl + A.